# Solving differential equation $x''(t)=x^6$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation
$$x''(t)=x^6(t)$$
If I had $x'(t)$ instead of $x''(t)$ the exercise would have been easier for me.

I would appreciate some help with this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: A way to avoid possible mix is to write it like that: $y''=x^6$ or $y''=y(t)^6$

Comment: i bet this will involve airy functions $Ai(x), Bi(x)$

Comment: $$\frac{x(t)^2 \left(\frac{2 x(t)^7}{7 c_1}+1\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{2};\frac{8}{7};-\frac{2 x(t)^7}{7 c_1}\right){}^2}{c_1+\frac{2 x(t)^7}{7}}=\left(c_2+t\right){}^2$$ I certainly wouldn't know how to get this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $$y = \frac{dx}{dt}.$$  then we have $$\frac{dx}{dt} = y, \frac{dy}{dt} = x^6.$$ dividing one by the other gives $$ y\, dy - x^6 dx= 0$$ which has the integral $$y = \pm \sqrt{\frac27}\sqrt{k + x^7} \to  
 t=   \pm \sqrt{\frac72}\int_0^x \frac{dx}{\sqrt{k + x^7}}$$

Comment: Can we always solve in this way problems, say, of the form $x''(t) = f(x(t))$ due to the autonomous character of the ODE?

Comment: @Dmoreno, in fact you can do this  for more general systems called gradient systems given by $x'' = -V'(x)$ where $V$ is called the poetntial function. the total energy $E = \frac12 x'^2 + V(x)$ is constant along the trajectories of this equation. that is what made it possible to convert the second order equation to a first order equation $y = \frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{2(E-V(x))}.$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x' =u(x) $ the we have $$x'' =u'(x) x' =u'u $$ so we obtain $$u'u =x^6$$ hence $$udu =x^6 dx$$ and therefore $$u^2=\frac{2}{7} x^7 +C. $$ Hence $$t+C_1 =\pm\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{7} x^7 +C}}.$$

Comment: But what do you do from there? (you can also get the same differential equation by multiplying each side of the original one by $x^\prime$, but in the end you still end up with something like $(x^\prime)^2 = \frac{2}{7}x^7 + C$ to solve).